# I wanna show TABBAR controller in modal view from 1 tab

Tags: iphone, xcode, show, tabbar

I made a tabbar-based controllers with 5 tabs
and at 1st tab, there's a button to call a modal view.

but when a modal view showed up, there's no tabbar on it.

How do I show a tabbar at that presented modal view ?

Answer (score 0):

For example if FirstViewController is the first viewController for your first tabbar, you should do like this:

[FirstViewController.view addSubview:theViewYouWantToShow];

Comment: HotViewController.h / .m   <-- 1st tabbar view
SecondViewController.h / .m  <-- the view controller that i wanna show on

then I typed like this

[self addSubview:SecondViewController.view];

then, error occurs, saying "property 'view' not found on object type of 'SecondViewcontroller' "

what's wrong with that? How do I set the property of SecondViewController's view??

Comment: first you create your instanse of SecondViewController and then add by [self.view addSubView :secondviewvc.view]

Answer (score 0):

If you'll call a `viewController` using `presentModelViewController`, it'll hide the tabbar of the application. You can use either of 2 way:

1. Set `navigationController` in first `tab` and `push` `anotherViewController` (without animation if you don't wanna show push effect)
2. Or as Sumit suggested add `anotherViewController.view` as subView on `firstViewController`